# Power Automate flow triggerede by "When a row is added, modified or deleted" not triggered

Tags: dynamics-crm, workflow, power-automate, dataverse

I'm new to Microsoft CRM and Power Automate. I'm trying to implement the Quote approval process.

As the first step, I tried to create a simple workflow to trigger when a Quote item is saved/modified using Dataverse 'When a row is added, modified or deleted'. So, I have studied many online tutorials and done workflow very simple to send an email when a Quote item is saved/modified.

Problem is, It's actually not triggered with any action on the Quote page. Already spend a couple of days to figure out the issue.

This is how I tested it.

*Step 01* - Save and test manually test flow
[image]

*Step 02* - insert a new item to Quote or modify the existing item.

[image]

But nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was Administrative mode.

Administrative mode disables all asynchronous processes. This includes server-side sync (email synchronization) and workflow processes including flow (Power Automate).

https://functionalthoughts.com/microsoft-dynamics-365-managing-admin-mode-from-power-platform/

Answer (score 2):

Items you add to the Quote are in fact Quote Product records. This is a separate table named `quotedetail`.

Your Power Automate flow needs to target the Quote Products table to capture the intended changes.